# How do you find a and b in a ln function from (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function

Like I was looking at one answer from JohnD
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/52893/johnd
and he answered that to find a and b of a ln function, you have to use 
a=y1−y2ln(x1/x2), b=exp(y2ln(x1)−y1ln(x2)y1−y2).

My question is that HOW do you get to the a and b??

Original Question:
[Graphing: Given two points on a graph, find the logarithmic function that passes through both.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716152/graphing-given-two-points-on-a-graph-find-the-logarithmic-function-that-passes)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve legibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Another way to do it (for the same result)*

Starting with 
$$y_1=a\log(b\,x_1)=a \log(b)+a\log(x_1)\tag 1$$
$$y_2=a\log(b\,x_2)=a \log(b)+a\log(x_2)\tag 2$$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$
$$y_2-y_1=a\log(x_2)-a\log(x_1)\implies \color{blue}{a=\frac{y_2-y_1 } {\log(x_2)-\log(x_1) }}$$ Now, rewrite $(1)$ and $(2)$ as
$$\frac {y_1} a=\log(bx_1)\implies e^{\frac {y_1} a}=b x_1 \tag 3$$
$$\frac {y_2} a=\log(bx_2)\implies e^{\frac {y_2} a}=b x_2 \tag 4$$
Subtracting $(3)$ from $(4)$
$$e^{\frac {y_2} a}-e^{\frac {y_1} a}=b(x_2-x_1)\implies \color{blue}{b=\frac{e^{\frac {y_2} a}-e^{\frac {y_1} a} }{x_2-x_1 }}$$

Comment: Thank you soooooo much this helped a lot

Comment: @SimyMany. You are very welcome ! The results are the same, be sure. Cheers.