# Graphing: Given two points on a graph, find the logarithmic function of base 10 that passes through both

Tags: functions, polynomials, logarithms, graphing-functions

This is almost exactly the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716152/graphing-given-two-points-on-a-graph-find-the-logarithmic-function-that-passes) but I am having hard time getting the results when we want to find the formula of function $\log_{10}$
thas passes through both points instead of $\ln$.